# Export Wizard extremely slow when exporting tables to CSV

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to export my tables to CSV using the guide on:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html

the export runs extremely slow and then ultimatively fails. Is there any way to circumvent this?

It fails even for tables around 50 MB.

Anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in MySQL making the export wizard extremely slow when exporting larger files.

Use a code instead to export the file.

Forexample one can use:

```
SELECT variables
INTO OUTFILE 'nameoffile.csv' CHARACTER SET 'UTF8MB4'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FROM "table to export";
```